# Networking - Unbiquiti over 2 subnets

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubiquiti

Just a quick question.

We have just bought 2 of the ubiquiti network p2p bridges here:
https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/nanobeam-ac-gen2/

I have one office on 192.168.1.X and the other across the road on 192.168.0.X

My question is what would be best, using these in router mode and connecting them or using them in bridge mode, connecting them and using Routing and remote access on each of the windows server 2008 r2's to handle the routing. Is there a best practice  or just whatever "feels" best?

All our clients are Subnet 255.255.255.0 and have both DNS and default Gateway pointing to each server at present.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how and where the server boxes are connected. But anyway in general I don't like RRAS and think it would overcomplicate this scenario; do the routing on the NanoBeams. If setting both as router you'll need a third subnet as a point-to-point between them and a static route configured on each to point to the opposite office subnet across that point to point.

Alternatively you could put one in router mode, the other in bridge and then you don't need the extra point-to-point subnet.